# Using CodeDom with C# Web Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications, builder, codedom

I've finished builder for my application using C# Windows Application Forms.
I'm using CodeDom.
How it works:
User input some details like: name, lastname etc... and when he click Build application compiles several classes into one .exe file with those details embeded into it.

Now I want to make online builder for my application but I'm having problems with CodeDom.
I've created webapp forms and buttons (same ID's as in my Windows Form Application) and embeded my CodeDom code into App_Code folder. When I debug it it loads page just fine, but when I enter info and press Build nothing happens.

I've used this for Error detection in my Windows Form Application

```
foreach (CompilerError compile_error in cResults.Errors)
{
    CompilerError error = compile_error;
    Console.Beep();
    Console.WriteLine("Error: " + error.ErrorText + "\r\n" + error.Line, "");
}
```

I tried using same thing on my webapp but all I get is Beep, no Console.Writeline so I don't know what is the problem.
Maybe I can't use same syntax for codedom in webapp?

Comment: console in a web app?

Comment: I know it sounds stupid :D, This is first time I'm making webapp so I don't know how to show those errors.

Comment: You can use `Debug.WriteLine` while debugging...

Comment: The name 'Debug' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Come on, You can at least use google. It is in `System.Diagnostics` namespace (or rightclick on it and choose *resolve* :) )

Comment: Sorry for that, ok, I managed to fix errors, now can you please tell me where to look for .exe output file :D, sorry for this, this is my first time making webapp.

Comment: Maybe you should get a little clue about [ASP.NET](http://asp.net) before digging in so deep.